# Not able to forward GIF as GIF

Tags: oneplus-3

I am using OnePlus 3.  I am able to receive GIF Images but when I forward it to others on WhatsApp they are forwarded either as Still Images or Videos.

My friend is using Samsung A8, she can receive GIF on WhatsApp and forward it as GIF.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if whatsapp support for GIF is official or whether it's only made available in Beta channel.

Please check  `/sdcard/whatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Animated Gifs/` directory and see if you have .gif or .mp4 Since there is a feature in whatsapp where in you may convert short mp4 videos into gifs.

You will find more information on how to share videos as a gif [here](http://www.androidpolice.com/2016/08/25/slowly-happening-can-now-send-videos-gifs-whatsapp/)

> 1. Tap the attachment icon in any WhatsApp conversation
> 2. Choose Camera, then Record video
> 3. Record the video and select OK
> 4. In WhatsApp's interface for trimming the video, tap the upper right corner camcorder icon, it'll switch to a GIF icon Send.